# ListView inside a ListItem displays only one entry

Tags: java, android, listview, android-arrayadapter

Inside my original Activity, I initialize an Adapter to populate a `ListView` and that goes smoothly. `ArrayList` populated with all the data gets passed as an argument to the Adapter and everything goes well.

Now inside that Adapter, or that `ListView` that gets populated, there's another `ListView` and another Adapter for it.

Again, I follow the same procedure and populate the Adapter with an `ArrayList`, but it seems as though only the first entry gets displayed in the nested `ListView`. I assume this is is because the parent `ListView` gets populated and the data for the child `ListView` only populates for one parents entry.

Anyway, here's the adapter initialization and the Adapter class:

```
    PlayerSeasonsStatsAdapter pssAdapter = new PlayerSeasonsStatsAdapter(getContext(), alPlayerSeasonsStats);
            vh.lvPlayerSeasonsStats.setAdapter(pssAdapter);
```

`alPlayerSeasonsStats` is an ArrayList containing data to populate the child `ListView`.

Here's the child Adapter:

```
public class PlayerSeasonsStatsAdapter extends ArrayAdapter{
    private ArrayList<PlayerStatsTeamModelSeasons> playerSeasons = new ArrayList<PlayerStatsTeamModelSeasons>();
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;

    public PlayerSeasonsStatsAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<PlayerStatsTeamModelSeasons> playerSeasons) {
        super(context, 0, playerSeasons);
        this.playerSeasons = playerSeasons;
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @Override
    public PlayerStatsTeamModelSeasons getItem(int position) {
        return playerSeasons.get(position);
    }


    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder vh;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.player_seasons_stats_row, parent, false);
            vh = new ViewHolder();
            vh.tvPSSRCompetition = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvPSSRCompetition);
            vh.tvPSSRMatchesPlayed = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvPSSRMatchesPlayed);
            vh.tvPSSRGoalsScored = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvPSSRGoalsScored);
            vh.tvPSSRAssists = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvPSSRAssists);
            vh.tvPSSRYellowCards = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvPSSRYellowCards);
            vh.tvPSSRRedCards = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvPSSRRedCards);
            vh.ivPSSRCompetitionLogo = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ivPSSRCompetitionLogo);
            convertView.setTag(vh);
        } else {
            vh = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

        }
        PlayerStatsTeamModelSeasons pstmsModel = getItem(position);

        vh.tvPSSRCompetition.setText(pstmsModel.pstmSeasonModel.name);
        vh.tvPSSRMatchesPlayed.setText(pstmsModel.pstmsModel.matchesPlayed);
        vh.tvPSSRGoalsScored.setText(pstmsModel.pstmsModel.goalsScored);
        vh.tvPSSRAssists.setText(pstmsModel.pstmsModel.assists);
        vh.tvPSSRYellowCards.setText(pstmsModel.pstmsModel.yellowCards);
        int totalRedCards = Integer.parseInt(pstmsModel.pstmsModel.yellowRedCards) + Integer.parseInt(pstmsModel.pstmsModel.redCards);
        vh.tvPSSRRedCards.setText(totalRedCards + "");
        //loadLogoToView(vh.ivPSSRCompetitionLogo, pstmsModel.pstmSeasonModel.id, true);
        return convertView;
    }

    public static void loadLogoToView(ImageView iv, String teamId, boolean transform) {
        String image = Constant.IMAGES_ROOT +
                Constant.LOGO_PATH +
                teamId +
                Constant.LOGO_EXTENSION;
        RequestCreator img = Picasso.with(iv.getContext())
                .load(image);
        if (transform) img.transform(new RoundedCornersTransform(2));
        img.into(iv);
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        ImageView ivPSSRCompetitionLogo;
        TextView tvPSSRCompetition;
        TextView tvPSSRMatchesPlayed;
        TextView tvPSSRGoalsScored;
        TextView tvPSSRAssists;
        TextView tvPSSRYellowCards;
        TextView tvPSSRRedCards;
    }
```

What are my options here?

Comment: I would start by not having a `ListView` nested in another `ListView`. Use a single `ListView` with multiple row types, or use an `ExpandableListView`, or use a `RecyclerView` with some sort of expansion semantics, or use a `RecyclerView` with multiple item types, or use a `vertical` `LinearLayout` instead of the nested `ListView`, or use something that works along the other axis (e.g., `HorizontalScrollView`), or use two activities/fragments (top-level `ListView` drilling down into a separate set of details with the formerly-nested `ListView`), etc.

Comment: I heard that nested ListViews cause UI problems, but with my design as simple as it is, it won't be an issue. That being said, is there anything I can do to fix the existing logic before choosing to start all over?

Comment: can look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31458803/listview-inside-listview-only-one-element

Comment: But the problem isn't that it displays a `ListView` with space for only 1 item, the problem is that the `ArrayList` used to populate the `ListView` via Adapter only contains one entry.

Comment: Then your problem lies with how you are populating `alPlayerSeasonsStats`, if it has `size()` of 1.

Comment: then check your `arraylist.add()`...code

Comment: Actually, I just ran the debugger and it turns out I was wrong... The `alPlayerSeasonsStats` indeed contains all the items, except that only one is displayed. Sorry, wrong assumption.

Answer (score 0):

Your Adapter should be look like

```
public class PlayerSeasonsStatsAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<PlayerStatsTeamModelSeasons> {

private  class ViewHolder {
    TextView tvPSSRCompetition;
}

public PlayerSeasonsStatsAdapter(Context context, List<PlayerStatsTeamModelSeasons> balanceModels) {

    super(context, R.layout.row_account_balance, balanceModels);

}

@Override

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    PlayerStatsTeamModelSeasons model = getItem(position);

    PlayerSeasonsStatsAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder;
    if (convertView == null) {

        viewHolder = new PlayerSeasonsStatsAdapter.ViewHolder();

        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());

        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_account_balance, parent, false);

        viewHolder.tvPSSRCompetition = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvPSSRCompetition);
        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);

    } else {

        viewHolder = (PlayerSeasonsStatsAdapter.ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    viewHolder.tvPSSRCompetition.setText(model.getPSSRCompetition());


    if (position%2== 0) {
        convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#F5EEE5"));
    }else{

        convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
    }

    return convertView;

   }

  }
```

Just Call below like

```
   PlayerSeasonsStatsAdapter adapter = new PlayerSeasonsStatsAdapter(MainActivity.this, balanceList);
   listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Listview Look like bellow

```
        <ListView
         android:id="@+id/listView"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent" />
        </LinearLayout>
```

here is row_account_balance layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"  >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvPSSRCompetition"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center|center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:text="@string/agent_statement_sl"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:paddingLeft="2dp"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"/>   
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: where did you make changes ? maybe adding some explanation how it will solve the problem will help the op..