# Collapsing ToolBar Layout with viewpager

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I am using CollapsingBarLayout with viewpager and the fragments of viewpager are having listview, gridview.

Here is my code:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.bigsteptech.seandroidnativeapp.classes.modules.common.ViewGroupEvent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
            app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@style/TransparentText">

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/carouselLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/coverImage"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:gravity="bottom"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                    android:padding="@dimen/profile_image_margin"
                    android:background="@drawable/gradient_bg"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/profile_image_margin"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_xlarge"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:textColor="@color/white"
                        android:id="@+id/content_title"/>

                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/profile_image_margin"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:textStyle="bold"
                            android:textColor="@color/white"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_medium"
                            android:id="@+id/category_title"/>

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:textStyle="bold"
                            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/category_title"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/profile_image_margin"
                            android:textColor="@color/white"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_medium"
                            android:id="@+id/memberCount"/>

                    </RelativeLayout>


                </LinearLayout>

            </FrameLayout>

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:theme="@style/ActionBarThemeOverlay"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ActionBarPopupThemeOverlay"
                android:background="@drawable/gradient_bg"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical"
        android:isScrollContainer="true"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/contentInfo"
                android:paddingBottom="48sp"
                android:clipToPadding="false"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <ProgressBar
                    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/profile_page_left_right_margin"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:id="@+id/progressBar"/>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:background="@color/grey_light">

                    <TextView android:id="@+id/ownerTitle"
                        android:clickable="true"
                        android:focusable="true"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/keyline_1"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"
                        android:textColor="@color/body_text_1" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/profile_image_margin"
                    android:padding="10dp">

                    <com.bigsteptech.seandroidnativeapp.Classes.Modules.Common.ViewRelated.ExpandableTextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/keyline_1"
                        style="@style/TextBody"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:id="@+id/view_description" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                    android:id="@+id/slidingTabs"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    app:tabIndicatorHeight="3dp"
                    app:tabMode="scrollable"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

                <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                    android:id="@+id/pager"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="300dp">

                </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>


            </LinearLayout>


        </RelativeLayout>

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/appbar"
        android:id="@+id/joinGroupButton"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_new"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:clickable="true"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

The fragments which are having listview, gridview do not scroll to up in collapsing toolBar, how can I achieve this working..

Please help me, thank you so much in advanced...

Comment: I want to design a layout like:

1. Collapsing ToolBar.
2. NestedScrollview having 2-3 textview.
3. Below these textviews, in same nestedscrollvew, I have some Tabs with Viewpager.
4. I am having fragments with listview and gridview.
5. Now the scrolling is not working fine with these listview and gridview.

How can I achieve this funcationality, can you please help me.

Comment: Have you checked my code?i have implemented what you need and more

Comment: Do not use nestedScrollView, RecyclerView or ListView conflicts scrolling.

Comment: Did you solve this problem?

Answer (score 9):

You need put your ViewPager inside AppBar section and setup **layout_behavior** :

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>>
    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
     // THIS VIEWS WILL BE COLLAPSED
    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    // THIS VIEWS WILL BE PINNED
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
          android:id="@+id/pager"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="300dp"
          app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

If you using Fragments as children of ViewPager you need setup **layout_behavior** to each fragment inside ViewPager too.

```
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I understand the above code and have already implemented it. But my problem is that I need to put some more content above the viewpager tabs, like some textviews and then need to put the viewpager. 

So, I need to put all these things in NestedScrollview, to enable collapsing effect.

How can I work for this, please help me.. :)

Comment: @PrithnirajNicyone ok, i got it. This is a bad idea. You need a single scroll handling layout - ScrollView, ListView, etc. Read more here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3495890/how-can-i-put-a-listview-into-a-scrollview-without-it-collapsing

Comment: @PrithnirajNicyone i think i have an idea how to help you. If you haven't any items below ListView you can use non-scrollable ListView, more detailed here : http://stackoverflow.com/a/24629341/2956344. And play with http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#attr_android:descendantFocusability

Answer (score 2):

collapsing toolbar with tabs using new material design support library

[image]

I used official collapsing toolbar feature of new material design support library.

here collapsed view height is 256dp and tabs height is 56dp

i made following path

i cut image into two parts one for collapsed view and one for tabs.

i cutted images according to [dp to pixel](http://androidpixels.net/) sizes with high resolution drawable xxxhdpi and put into drawable folder so it will adjustable to all screen sizes

i have 2000x1246 image

top image 256dp= 2000x1024 pixel

bottom tab image 56dp= 2000x224 pixel

Here is the complete example with [source code](http://blog.nkdroidsolutions.com/collapsing-toolbar-with-tabs-android-example/)

Answer (score 1):

`ListView` and `GridView` are not equipped with `NestedScrolling` functions. And thats needed to work with the `CollapsingToolbarLayout`.

The easiest way to make it work, would be to change your `ListView` and `GridView` to [`RecyclerViews`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/NestedScrollingChild.html) (`RecyclerView` implements [`NestedScrollingChild`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/NestedScrollingChild.html)).

Comment: My requirements are like that I cannot change my listview to Recyclerview.. Can you please give me some hint how can I use listview with nestedScrollview.

Thank you so much.. :)

Comment: you are right but there is a workaround for this issue i have implemented a grid view inside a list view with static grid view height calculated after creating the grid view

Comment: And by "my requirements are like that", you mean "I already did that, and don't wanna rewrite the code" :) ? I won't help you making `ListView` implement NestedScolling, because I would never bother. That would take much longer than rewriting your `ListView` and `GridView`.

Comment: I'm sorry @Tony but that sounds like a such a terrible idea... If I understand correctly you're forcing your `GridView` to show the full height of all items in it. Therefore you're disabling the only thing that makes `GridView` usable - which is reusing its `Views`

Comment: the idea of reusing is still exist and i didn't posted the code bcuz thats not what he want

Comment: The idea - maybe, but it doesn't work If you force `GridView's` to the height of all `Views`, it doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

i have achieved this i will put my code with the library used
firstly this is the layout file

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/attraction_lay"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#f5f6f5">

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="47dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/exp_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:text="See &amp; do"
        android:textColor="#1b7bba"
        android:textSize="17sp" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relmenu"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="17dp"
            android:layout_height="14dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="17dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:src="@drawable/menu_icon_blue" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relsearch"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="18dp"
            android:layout_height="18dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="17dp"

            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:src="@drawable/search_icon_blue" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>

<View
    android:id="@+id/div"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="2px"
    android:layout_below="@+id/bar"
    android:background="#1b7bba" />

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    android:layout_below="@+id/div">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:divider="@null"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
        android:scrollbars="none" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="290dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/images_header"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="250dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="40dp">

            <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/gallery"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="250dp"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:focusable="false"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
                android:overScrollMode="never" />

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/gallery_back"

                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="20dp"
                    android:layout_height="52dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:background="@drawable/arrow_back" />
            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/gallery_next"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical">

                <ImageView

                    android:layout_width="20dp"
                    android:layout_height="52dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:background="@drawable/arrow_next" />
            </RelativeLayout>

            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginBottom="-150dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="170dp"
                android:background="@drawable/horizontal_gradient" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/pagenum"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="right|bottom"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:text="3/15"
                android:textColor="#FFF"
                android:textSize="14sp" />

        </FrameLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/header_text_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"

            android:layout_height="@dimen/min_height_textheader_materiallike"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:background="#FFF">

            <!--<TextView-->
            <!--android:id="@+id/text_header"-->
            <!--android:layout_width="match_parent"-->
            <!--android:layout_height="wrap_content"-->
            <!--android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"-->
            <!--android:layout_marginLeft="70dp"-->
            <!--android:text="ttttt"-->
            <!--android:textColor="@android:color/white"-->
            <!--android:textSize="18sp"-->

            <!--android:textStyle="bold" />-->
            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/button_header"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="83dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="83dp">

                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:id="@+id/photo"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:layout_weight="2.5">

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="17dp"
                            android:layout_height="14dp"
                            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                            android:background="@drawable/photo_blue_icon"

                            />
                    </RelativeLayout>

                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:id="@+id/video"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="2.5">

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="14dp"
                            android:layout_height="16dp"
                            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                            android:background="@drawable/video_blue_icon" />
                    </RelativeLayout>

                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:id="@+id/share"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="2.5">

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="15dp"
                            android:layout_height="20dp"
                            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                            android:background="@drawable/share_blue_icon" />
                    </RelativeLayout>

                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:id="@+id/fav"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="2.5">

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="20dp"
                            android:layout_height="19dp"
                            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                            android:background="@drawable/fav_blue_icon" />
                    </RelativeLayout>

                </LinearLayout>

                <View
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="2px"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:background="#d7d7d7" />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </FrameLayout>

    </FrameLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

and in the java code you should add this

```
  StikkyHeaderBuilder.ListViewBuilder.stickTo(mListView)
                .setHeader(R.id.header, (ViewGroup) contentView)
                .minHeightHeaderDim(R.dimen.min_height_textheader_materiallike)
                .animator(new ParallaxStikkyAnimator())
                .attatch_Acitivty(Attractions.this)
                .castTo("Attractions")
                .build();
```

and here is the [library](https://github.com/carlonzo/StikkyHeader) used

but i have modified this library to work as i want

the modification is add method in stcikylistview builder to know the activity used and pass a delegate for scrolling i used this because i added a blur for images in the viewpager

and her is my modification

i will upload the modified version of the library
here you are https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxdN8PyW5nmHMmFFeFY2aW9zdlk/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue as well. You'll need to used RecyclerView. Now I understand you must use ListView and GridGiew, but you can use that within a RecyclerView.

For example, I'll show you how to implement a GridLayout within in a RecyclerView.

In your fragment layout (that you'd want to implement GridView in), add the following XML

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/recyclerviewGRID"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />
```

Then on your fragment java,

on your fragment onCreateView, define the RecyclerView,

```
RecyclerView rv = (RecyclerView) v.findViewById(R.id.recyclerviewGRID);
setupRecyclerView(rv);
```

Create the method setupRecyclerView,

```
 private void setupRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(recyclerView.getContext(), 2));
            mAdapter = new AdapterGridView(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), mItems);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    }
```

You must define mAdapter as `RecyclerView.Adapter` first. Then create your the adapter for the RecyclerView. Note that, mItems is an ArrayList that will contain contents of your list.

AdapterGridView.java

```
public class AdapterGridView extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterGridView.ViewHolder> {

    ArrayList<AdItem> mItems;
    Context context, contxt;

    public AdapterGridView(Context context, ArrayList<AdItem> mItems) {
        this.context = context;
        this.mItems = mItems;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {

//attach your list item layout here, mine in this case is called list_item_grid_item
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.list_item_grid_item, viewGroup, false);
        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(v);
        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
AdItem singleItem = mItems.get(i);

//attach data to your layout as the following manner
viewHolder.tvspecies.setText(singleItem.getName());

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {

//return the number of list items
        return mItems.size();
    }

    class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{

        public ImageView imgThumbnail, avatar;
        public TextView tvspecies, adIDLBL;


        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            itemView.setClickable(true);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);

//define your list item views, basically the stuff in list_item_grid_item
            imgThumbnail = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.img_thumbnail);
            tvspecies = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_species);

        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //handle item click events
        }
    }
}
```