# ListView in ScrollView not displaying all items Android

Tags: java, android, listview, scrollview

I have some problem `ListView` in `ScrollView` not displaying all items

and I try [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24629341/7639018), it works but it takes a long time to process in the Adapter.

I have tried [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24629341/7639018) which is faster but doesn't display all items

How do I fix it?

Note: my `ListView` id is `lv_poll_feed`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/color_white">

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/lay_edit_comment"
    android:scrollbars="none">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/lay_big"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/lay_body_timeline_detail_detail"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/view_line_4">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tx_time_timeline_detail_user"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text="-"
                android:textColor="@color/color_gray_light"
                android:textSize="@dimen/tx_size_smally_time"/>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/lay_profile_detail_detail"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/tx_time_timeline_detail_user"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="0dp">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tx_timeline_detail_detail"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:text="-"
                    android:textColor="@color/tx_color_token"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/tx_size_small"/>

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/lay_center"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/tx_timeline_detail_detail"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:visibility="visible">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/tx_catego_topic"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                            android:background="@drawable/bg_button"
                            android:padding="5dp"
                            android:text="xxxxxxx"
                            android:textColor="@color/color_white"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/tx_size_small"
                            android:visibility="gone"/>

                        <com.cunoraz.tagview.TagView xmlns:tagview="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                                                     android:id="@+id/tagCloudLinkView_topic"
                                                     android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                                     android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                                     android:layout_margin="10dp"
                                                     tagview:lineMargin="5dp"
                                                     tagview:tagMargin="5dp"
                                                     tagview:theme="@style/AppTheme"/>

                        <ListView
                            android:id="@+id/lv_poll_feed"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                            android:divider="@null"
                            android:visibility="visible">
                        </ListView>
                    </LinearLayout>
                </RelativeLayout>

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/img_timeline_profile_detail_list"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/tx_timeline_detail_detail"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:visibility="visible"/>
            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/lay_timeline_detail_emoji"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/lay_profile_detail_detail"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:focusable="false"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
                android:padding="10dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/lay_big_emoji"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:visibility="visible"
                    android:weightSum="3">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/lay_emoji1"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="0"
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:visibility="visible">

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="20dp"
                            android:layout_height="20dp"
                            android:src="@drawable/amazed_1"/>

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/tx_number_emoji_1"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                            android:text=""
                            android:textSize="@dimen/tx_size_smally_time"/>
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/lay_emoji2"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:layout_weight="0"
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:visibility="visible">

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="20dp"
                            android:layout_height="20dp"
                            android:src="@drawable/funny_2"/>

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/tx_number_emoji_2"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                            android:text=""
                            android:textSize="@dimen/tx_size_smally_time"/>
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/lay_emoji3"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:layout_weight="0"
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:visibility="visible">

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="20dp"
                            android:layout_height="20dp"
                            android:src="@drawable/love_3"/>

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/tx_number_emoji_3"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text=""
                            android:textSize="@dimen/tx_size_smally_time"/>
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/lay_emoji4"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:layout_weight="0"
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:visibility="visible">

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="20dp"
                            android:layout_height="20dp"
                            android:src="@drawable/sorrow_2"/>

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/tx_number_emoji_4"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                            android:text=""
                            android:textSize="@dimen/tx_size_smally_time"/>
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/lay_emoji5"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:layout_weight="0"
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:visibility="visible">

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="20dp"
                            android:layout_height="20dp"
                            android:src="@drawable/anger_5"/>

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/tx_number_emoji_5"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                            android:text=""
                            android:textSize="@dimen/tx_size_smally_time"/>
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/lay_emoji6"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:layout_weight="0"
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:visibility="visible">

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="20dp"
                            android:layout_height="20dp"
                            android:src="@drawable/horrified_6"/>

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/tx_number_emoji_6"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                            android:text=""
                            android:textSize="@dimen/tx_size_smally_time"/>
                    </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>
            </RelativeLayout>

            <View
                android:id="@+id/view_line_5"
                android:layout_below="@+id/lay_timeline_detail_emoji"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:background="@color/text_bottombar"/>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/lay_body_quest_topic"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/view_line_5"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:weightSum="6">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/lay_timeline_detail_up"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:layout_weight="2"
                        android:focusable="false"
                        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:padding="5dp">

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/img_up"
                            android:layout_width="20dp"
                            android:layout_height="20dp"
                            android:src="@drawable/up_1"/>

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/tx_timeline_detail_up"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                            android:text="@string/tx_up"
                            android:textColor="@color/tx_color_token"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/tx_size_smally"/>

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/tx_timeline_detail_number_up"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                            android:text=" 53"
                            android:textColor="@color/tx_color_token"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/tx_size_smally"/>
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/lay_timeline_detail_comment"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:layout_weight="2"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:padding="5dp">

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/img_comment"
                            android:layout_width="20dp"
                            android:layout_height="20dp"
                            android:src="@drawable/comment_1"/>

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/tx_timeline_detail_comment"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                            android:text="@string/tx_comment"
                            android:textColor="@color/tx_color_token"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/tx_size_smally"/>

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/tx_timeline_detail_number_comment"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                            android:text=" 53"
                            android:textColor="@color/tx_color_token"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/tx_size_smally"/>
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/lay_profile_detail_share"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:layout_weight="2"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:padding="5dp">

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="20dp"
                            android:layout_height="20dp"
                            android:src="@drawable/share_1"/>

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/tx_timeline_detail_share"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                            android:text="@string/tx_share"
                            android:textColor="@color/tx_color_token"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/tx_size_smally"/>

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/tx_timeline_detail_number_share"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                            android:text=" "
                            android:textColor="@color/tx_color_token"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/tx_size_smally"/>
                    </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>
            </RelativeLayout>

            <View
                android:id="@+id/view_line_3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="3dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/lay_body_quest_topic"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:background="@color/bottombar"/>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/lay_timeline_detail_select_emoji_profile"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_above="@+id/lay_body_quest_topic"
                android:layout_marginBottom="-10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/bg_emoji"
                android:visibility="gone">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/lay_star"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/tx_name_detail"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <RadioGroup
                        android:id="@+id/radioGroupQuest"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:padding="0dp">

                        <RadioButton
                            android:id="@+id/emoji1"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                            android:background="@drawable/img_emoji_amazed"
                            android:button="@android:color/transparent"
                            android:checked="false"
                            android:gravity="center"/>

                        <RadioButton
                            android:id="@+id/emoji2"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                            android:background="@drawable/img_emoji_funny"
                            android:button="@android:color/transparent"
                            android:checked="false"/>
                    </RadioGroup>
                </LinearLayout>
            </RelativeLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not add same direction scrolling layout inside another scrolling layout. Result will not always intended. Here your listview is wrapping to single element of your ListView because you have added it inside Scrollview. You should not do that in first place but if you can't change your layout then do the following changes:

1. Change **ListView** to **RecyclerVie**w and change the **adapter** accordingly.
2. Also, change **ScrollView** to **NestedScrollView**.

Comment: thanks! it's work when I change ListView to RecyclerView

Answer (score 2):

You can use this function :

```
public static void setListViewHeight(ListView listView) {
    ListAdapter listAdapter = listView.getAdapter();
    if (listAdapter == null)
        return;

    int desiredWidth = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(listView.getWidth(), MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
    int totalHeight = 0;
    View view = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < listAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
        view = listAdapter.getView(i, view, listView);
        if (i == 0)
            view.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(desiredWidth, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        view.measure(desiredWidth, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
        totalHeight += view.getMeasuredHeight();
    }
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = listView.getLayoutParams();
    params.height = totalHeight + (listView.getDividerHeight() * (listAdapter.getCount() - 1));
    listView.setLayoutParams(params);
}
```

and set like this :

```
ListView list = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listview);
setListViewHeight(list);
```

Comment: i try this is not work , listview is have scrollview

Comment: Have you tries this code after putting adapter in listview?

Comment: This works, while passing the Listview into this function